# How can I use reactstrap when CSS module is enable?

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

How can I use reactstrap when CSS module is enable? it seem reactstrap is not working properly. I use to call `css` by `className={classes.mycss}` but then I follow instruction here https://reactstrap.github.io/ and still it didnt work. Also I imported the `bootstrap css` in my `index.js`. Any idea how to fix this?

**index.js**

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
```

**myComponent**

```
import { Button } from 'reactstrap';
```

Answer (score 1):

There are certain problems with this approach:

1. CSS Modules localises the classnames to the module it is imported in, so if you import boostrap css, you will have to repeat that in every module.
2. CSS Modules requires classnames that are in camel case, which the bootstrap version is not.
3. Bootstrap styles are not written to be localised to a language. They are often meant to be shared.
4. Even if we use packages like [Bootstrap CSS Modules](https://github.com/adamelliotfields/bootstrap-css-modules), Reactstrap depends on the global classnames and will not work.

The way to the solve this problem might be to add bootstrap as a global stylesheet file and use `classNames` instead of CSS Modules specific `styleName`. 
You can do this by:

1. Adding a `link` tag to index.html file.

You can find the discussion [here](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules/issues/109)